# How to handle disposable resources within dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, idisposable

We have some data source classes which handle operations on disposable resources, like this:

```
public class SomeDataStore
{
    private readonly object dictionaryLock = new object();

    private readonly Dictionary<uint, SomeDisposableClass> dataStore = new Dictionary<uint, SomeDisposableClass>();

    public bool Remove(uint key)
    {
        bool returnValue = false;

        lock (dictionaryLock)
        {
            returnValue = dataStore.Remove(key);
        }

        //OR...

        lock (dictionaryLock)
        {
            SomeDisposableClass element;

            if (dataStore.TryGetValue(key, out element))
            {
                element.Dispose();
                returnValue = dataStore.Remove(key);
            }
        }

        return returnValue;
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        lock (dictionaryLock)
        {
            dataStore.Clear();
        }

        //OR...

        lock (dictionaryLock)
        {
            foreach (var value in dataStore.Values)
                value.Dispose();

            dataStore.Clear();
        }
    }

    //Some other Datastore access members
}

public class SomeDisposableClass : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        //Dispose resources..
    }
}
```

Not sure which version should be better and why? Does `Dictionary`'s `Clear` or `Remove` internally handle `disposable` resource?

Comment: Generally the code that calls `Dispose` on an object, was the one that created it in the first place.  It's somewhat dangerous for `SomeDataStore` to assume it has ownership of the object.  Hard to say as your code shows no signs of adding the object let alone who creates it

Comment: No, removing (be it via `Remove` or `Clear` or whatever) won´t call dipose, you have to do it on your own when done.

Comment: You may wish to consider using `ConcurrentDictionary` rather than `Dictionary` with a `lock`. _It won't solve your current issue though._

Comment: I would expect the method to be clearer about its intent - something like `RemoveAndDispose` - if it did actually call `Dispose`. Alternatively, have `Remove` return `SomeDisposableClass` so that the caller can do `SomeDataStore.Remove(key)?.Dispose()` if they wish.

Comment: It depends on how this class is used. For example I would be very surprised if I put my object into dictionary, removed it and had it disposed by doing that. However in your scenario that might be exactly what is expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why should an element within a dictionary be disposed automatically when removed from it? It might exist in another list or whatever anyway. Having said this it´s quite dangerous to dispose an object when removing it in some collection. None of the methods you mentioned (`Remove`, `Clear`, whatever) has any knowledge on disposable objects. All those methods do is to remove the *reference* to your  instance from the internal cache. Removing a reference to an object however doesn´t mean it should be released (GC) or even disposed (`IDisposable`). This in fact has nothing to do with disposable objects. Even the GC won´t release your object if there´s another reference to it existing in another list for example.

So you should allways dispose your ressources where you have control over them - which is usually in the same context where you created them.

Answer (score 2):

No, you should take care of Disposable objects your self. The dictionary does not take care of this.

Like Micky says, only when it has ownership on the objects.